# Making Sense of ISP's Network Topology

Tags: routing, nat, isp, traceroute

I recently noticed something odd while performing traceroutes from my home network, and its made me wonder as to the architecture of my ISP's network.

My home network uses 192.168.0.0/16 addresses (192.168.0.0/24 to be exact). When I perform a traceroute from my home network, the first three hops are:

1. My home network's gateway (192.168.0.1).
2. A 10.0.0.0/8 (i.e. RFC1918 private address), seemingly indicating that the near-side interface of the first hop in my ISP's network is using private addresses.
3. A public IP address, which I've confirmed is allocated to my ISP's ASN.

A bit of poking around has confirmed to me that I can receive responses from *tens of thousands* of 10.0.0.0/8 addresses, presumably the home gateways of other customers of my ISP.

When I look at the settings of my home gateway, I find two things:

- Its external IP address is *not* a 10.0.0.0/8 address, but rather a public address part of a range allocated to my ISP, and
- Its gateway (the address of its next hop) is also a public IP address allocated to my ISP and not a 10.0.0.0/8 address.

My suspicion is that my ISP is using carrier-grade NAT and assigning its customers 10.0.0.0/8 addresses. I'm wondering:

- **Does this indeed seem to be whats happening?**
- **If so, why is my home gateway assigned a public IP address rather than a 10.0.0.0/8 address, given that the near-side interface of the next hop has a 10.0.0.0/8 address?**

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it is similar to how my ISP does it as well... my router is assigned a 96.8.x.x address, the next hop is 10.11.0.1, then to a 24.220.x.x address and progresses through the ISP's network. This is more of a routing technique than NATing, they are just using private IP space to route through so as not too use up too much public IP address space. Remember traceroute shows you the network hops, not necessarily how the underlying routing is done.

Comment: Can you get `traceroute`s from outside your ISP back to your IP address? You can test from work, ask a friend, or try one of [these tools](http://www.traceroute.org/). Does your ISP do any kind of content filtering that you know of?

Comment: Also, when you go to any website ([example](http://www.ipchicken.com/)) that shows your public IP address, is it the same one as the address that shows up on your home gateway, or is it a different address?

Comment: Traceroute from a looking glass (e.g. http://lg.he.net/) back to my public IP address does indeed work, showing my public IP as the last hop. I don't know of any content filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Its doesn't look like carrier grade NAT - Carrier Grade nat is supposed to use [100.64.0.0/10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598#section-7).

Further than that, its a crap-shot as to what the ISP is doing without more information.  It may be they have assigned a large number of 10.x.x.x addresses for management of CPE devices or roadside cabinet equipment.

It could also be a device on their network - possibly a  [misconfigured](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/all-ips-in-a-subnet-behind-my-f5-respond-to-ping-even-though-i-only-have-4-devices-active) one, or maybe a legitimate one of a number of routers set up to handle failover.

Comment: That's not correct. Carrier Grade NAT is *supposed* to use 100.64.0.0/10, but many carriers, such as AT&T (both wired and wireless), are using 10.0.0.0/8. T-Mobile in the US actually uses addresses that belong to the US Military for their NAT.

Comment: If they are using 10.0.0.0 they are not doing carrier grade nat.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6598#section-7.  The tests would fail clause 3 "The Service Provider knows that the [RFC1918] address block that it uses to number interfaces between the CGN and CPE is not used on the subscriber side of the CPE".

Comment: @MosheKatz Also, Carrier Grade nat makes no sense as the OP stated he has a static IP.   As you voted me down, I'd be keen to see your answer.

Comment: Where do you see anything in the question about a static IP? Also, AT&T "solved" the problem with CGN and RFC1918 address blocks by [forcing customers to change their internal IP addresses](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2188898/lan-wan/at-t-demands-we-change-our-networks.html). T-Mobile "solved" the problem by using USDoD addresses for theirs. If it's not Carrier Grade NAT, what would you call what is being done by AT&T and T-Mobile?

Comment: @MosheKatz - sorry, public ip, not static

Comment: I can think of two possibilities: 1) Given the increasing public awareness of the existence of CGN, it could be that this ISP is trying to disguise its use of the technology by making it appear that the customer has a public address. 2) The ISP is trying to avoid the problem that AT&T had when it told customers they had to renumber their personal networks.

Comment: Given the additional information in the comments of the question, I will withdraw my downvote if you edit the question so that it unlocks the votes. (An easy fix would be to correct the spelling of "than" as "then" in the second line.) Nevertheless the statement that carriers are only using CGN if they use the official CGN address space is still wrong.

Comment: Looping back here. I found this question (http://superuser.com/questions/777866/why-is-tracert-showing-a-private-ip-address-right-after-my-router-even-though-i) which asks essentially the same thing I did, and one of the answer's suggests that the 10.0.0.0/8 I'm seeing right after my router is the CMTS that my modem connects to.